# Merge two Maps of type Map<String, Set<String>>

Tags: lambda, merge, java-8, set, java-stream

I have two maps of type `Map<String, Set<String>>` that I need to merge based on the key of each. I'm using Java 8.

I have tried the following:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> collect = Stream.of(keyColumnValueAccumulator, keyColumnValues)
                .map(Map::entrySet)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey, 
                        Map.Entry::getValue));
```

But at runtime this results in a 'Duplicate Key' error. Please can someone help? I'm still quite new to Java 8 and the Stream API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to decide what to do in case of a key collision:

for example, you could merge the two sets into one then return the new merged result:

```
 Stream.of(keyColumnValueAccumulator, keyColumnValues)
       .map(Map::entrySet)
       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Map.Entry::getKey,
             Map.Entry::getValue,
            (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;}));
```

or you can keep the first and discard the second:

```
 Stream.of(keyColumnValueAccumulator, keyColumnValues)
           .map(Map::entrySet)
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Map.Entry::getKey,
                 Map.Entry::getValue,
                (left, right) -> left);
```

or the reciprocal:

```
Stream.of(keyColumnValueAccumulator, keyColumnValues)
           .map(Map::entrySet)
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Map.Entry::getKey,
                 Map.Entry::getValue,
                (left, right) -> right);
```

or call another function to compute the new value and so forth...

Comment: But we are dealing with Sets and sets are unordered collections of unique values

Comment: @Johno Okay, and what in my answer makes you say that? what do you want to do when there is a key collision?

Comment: Oh, hang on, I'm getting confused with key vs value collisions. I understand now. I've been working on this for too long!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [Map::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method to avoid the duplicate key error.

Example:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> accumulator = new HashMap<>();
firstMap.forEach((k, v) -> accumulator.merge(k, v, (prev, cur) -> {prev.addAll(cur); return prev;}));
secondMap.forEach((k, v) -> accumulator.merge(k, v, (prev, cur) -> {prev.addAll(cur); return prev;}));
```

In the case of a key collision, we simply accumulate the two sets into one, but if this is not the desired behaviour you can always alter it or create a custom function for the `remappingFunction`.